# How can I search a folder AND its sub-folders for a certain file and then get the file of it? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, fs, directory-structure

I am building a npm module and I want to search the user's folder and its subfolders for a file (ex. `config.json`).

So basically I need a function which takes in the file name as an parameter and returns the file's path.

Can someone help me?

Comment: So, you're basically doing a file search on the user's storage device(s)? It has to find the file first before displaying the file's path?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to find the file and then return the file path.

Answer (score 0):

This will search recursively and return the found file(s) as an array.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const search = async (targetPath, findFile) => {
  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(targetPath);
  const result = [];

  for (let file of files) {
    try {
      const filepath = path.join(targetPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.promises.lstat(filepath);

      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        const childFiles = await fs.promises.readdir(filepath);
        files.push(...childFiles.map((f) => path.join(file, f))); 
      }

      if (stats.isFile() && path.basename(file) === findFile) {
        result.push(filepath);
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const found = await search('path/to/search', 'config.json');
    console.log(found);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

run();
```